# How to index unknown fields of a known field in PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query, pymongo

I am trying to find unique words in millions of tweets and also I want to keep where each word appears. In addition to that, I am also grouping the words by their initial. Here is a sample code:

```py
from pymongo import UpdateOne
# connect to db stuff
for word in words: # this is actually not the real loop I've used but it fits for this example
    # assume tweet_id's and position is calculated here
    initial = word[0]
    ret = {"tweet_id": tweet_id, "pos": (beg, end)} # additional information about word
    command = UpdateOne({"initial": initial}, {"$inc": {"count": 1}, "$push": {"words.%s" % word: ret}}, upsert=True)
    commands.append(command)
    if len(commands) % 1000 == 0:
        db.tweet_words.bulk_write(commands, ordered=False)
        commands = []
```

However, this is way slow to analyze all those tweets. I am guessing that my problem occurs because I don't use an index on `words` field.

Here is an sample output of a document:

```
{
    initial: "t"
    count: 3,
    words: {
        "the": [{"tweet_id": <some-tweet-id>, "pos": (2, 5)}, 
                {"tweet_id": <some-other-tweet-id>, "pos": (9, 12)}]
        "turkish": [{"tweet_id": <some-tweet-id>, "pos": (5, 11)}]
    }
}
```

I've tried to create indexes using the following codes (unsuccessfully):

```
db.tweet_words.create_index([("words.$**", pymongo.TEXT)])
```

or

```
db.tweet_words.create_index([("words", pymongo.HASHED)])
```

I've got errors like `add index fails, too many indexes for twitter.tweet_words` or `key too large to index`. Is there a way to do this with indexes? Or should change my approach the problem (maybe redesign the db)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be indexed, you need to keep your dynamic data in the values of the objects, not the keys. So I'd suggest you rework your schema to look like:

```
{
    initial: "t"
    count: 3,
    words: [
        {value: "the", tweets: [{"tweet_id": <some-tweet-id>, "pos": (2, 5)}, 
                                {"tweet_id": <some-other-tweet-id>, "pos": (9, 12)}]},
        {value: "turkish", tweets: [{"tweet_id": <some-tweet-id>, "pos": (5, 11)}]}
    ]
}
```

Which you could then index as:

```
db.tweet_words.create_index([("words.value", pymongo.TEXT)])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have an additional question to this. In near future, ı would like to get a list of words that start with let's say the letter `t`. How can I accomplish this query without any overhead? Currently, I can query that words with this: `cur = db.tweet_words.find({"initial": initial})` and `words = list(next(cur)["words"])`

The code is a bit messy but hopefully, you get the main idea.

Comment: @TalhaÇolakoğlu Best to post that as a new question.

Comment: Not sure if this one needs a new post too but here it is: To accomplish the schema you mention, how should I change the current update command?

Comment: @TalhaÇolakoğlu Yeah, any non-trivial followup question should be a new post.