# How to make a list from all values in a field in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I have a word database that has the following structure:

```
{
    initial: "t"
    count: 3,
    words: [
        {value: "the", tweets: [{"tweet_id": <some-tweet-id>, "pos": (2, 5)}, 
                                {"tweet_id": <some-other-tweet-id>, "pos": (9, 12)}]},
        {value: "turkish", tweets: [{"tweet_id": <some-tweet-id>, "pos": (5, 11)}]}
]
```

}

I am storing all unique words that are present million of tweets and their positions in this db. The question is that I would like to list all words that start with an initial easily. To make it more clear, I would like to do something similar to this:

```
cur = db.tweet_words.find({"initial": initial})
words = list(next(cur)["words"])
```

How can achieve this without distorting the current schema of the database? (To see why I need to preserve the schema refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53892553/how-to-index-unknown-fields-of-a-known-field-in-pymongo) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`distinct`](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.distinct) to do this:

```
db.tweet_words.distinct("words.value", {"initial": initial})
```

Output:

```
[ "the", "turkish" ]
```